# Prefetch_related on queryset.get()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Today I have written a DRF view method using `prefetch_related`:

```
def post(self, request, post_uuid, format=None):
        post = Post.objects.prefetch_related('postimage_set').get(uuid=post_uuid)
        postimage_set = post.postimage_set.all()
        for image in postimage_set:
            ...
        return Response('', status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And I fear that I am using `prefetch_related` wrongfully with this. Does it make sense to use `prefetch_related` here or will this fetch all `posts` as well as all `postimages` and then filter this set to just one instance? I'm super thankful for any help on this.

Comment: It will not make a difference *at all*. The `.prefetch_related` results in one extra query. So *without* using `.prefetch_related(..)` it will still make the *same* queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks kinda unnatural. Without looking at your database structure I can only guess, that what you really want to do is:
`PostImage.objects.filter(post__uuid=post_uuid)` (mind the usage of a dunder between `post` and `uuid` - that simple trick follow the relation attribute) which should result in a single query.

Moreover, if you are uncertain of a number of queries that will hit the database, you can write a very precise test with one of the assertions, that is available since Django 1.3: [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries)